# Teradata SQL assistant by default works in ANSI mode

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Once for no reason Teradata sql assistant has started to work in ANSI mode, as result `help view ..., show view, sel` stopped to work:

[image]
[image]

After connection creating new sheets by ctrl+N - creates normal sheet, everything work well there:
[image]

However reconnecting breaks everything, so one more time is needeed to create working sheets.

Session mode is Teradata:
[image]

Versions:

[image]

It doesnt show any my connection lines:
[image]
How to fix this?

UPD1:

```
Log (deleted old and unsuccessful connections):
*******************************************************
20.08.2018 9:58:38
SQLA Version: 16.10.0.2
Driver Version: Teradata.Net 16.10.0.0
Teradata.Client.Provider.TdException (0x80004005): [.NET Data Provider for Teradata] [100002] Cannot create connection within the time specified.
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpTcpTransport.<>c.<WaitOnSockets>b__52_0()
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.UtlStopwatchWrapper.GetTimeRemaining(Int32 timeout, Action timeoutAction)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpTcpTransport.WaitOnSockets(List`1 sockets, UtlStopwatchWrapper timer, Int32 timeout, Int32 lccTimeout, TdErrorCollection errors)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpTcpTransport.Connect(UtlStopwatchWrapper timer, Int32 timeout)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpSession.OpenTransport(UtlStopwatchWrapper timer, Int32 connectionTimeout)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpSession.Open(Int32 connectionTimeout, String password)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.ExeContext`3.Open(Int32 timeout, String password)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.Connection.Open(UtlConnectionString connectionString, UInt32 timeout)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.ConnectionFactory.GetConnection(Object owningObject, UtlConnectionString connStr)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.TdConnection.Open()
   в Teradata.SQLA.TdConnectInfo.GetSession() в v:\cm.client.ttu16.x\tdcli\qman\sqla\TdConnectInfo.vb:строка 202
*******************************************************
28.08.2018 14:38:05
SQLA Version: 16.10.0.2
Driver Version: Teradata.Net 16.10.0.0
System.Exception: Exception handled in FpSpread.WndProc ---> System.NullReferenceException:  
   в FarPoint.Win.Spread.SpreadView.a(Int32 A_0, MouseEventArgs A_1)
   в FarPoint.Win.Spread.SpreadView.g(MouseEventArgs A_0)
   в FarPoint.Win.Spread.FpSpread.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в FarPoint.Win.Spread.FpSpread.WndProc(Message& m)
   --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
   в FarPoint.Win.Spread.FpSpread.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
*******************************************************
13.09.2018 10:03:19
SQLA Version: 16.10.0.2
System.InvalidOperationException: Cant call Invoke or BeginInvoke on a control until the window handle has been completed.
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method)
   в Teradata.SQLA.RunQry.ExecuteStatement() в v:\cm.client.ttu16.x\tdcli\qman\sqla\RunQry.vb:строка 645
   в Teradata.SQLA.RunQry._Lambda$__3(Object a0) в v:\cm.client.ttu16.x\tdcli\qman\sqla\RunQry.vb:строка 357
   в System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   в System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   в System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
*******************************************************
23.10.2018 18:08:44
SQLA Version: 16.10.0.2
Driver Version: Teradata.Net 16.10.0.0
Teradata.Client.Provider.TdException (0x80004005): [.NET Data Provider for Teradata] [100015] Total size of all parcels is greater than the max message size.
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.Request.VerifyRequestDoesNotExceedMaxBuffer(TeraTypeBase[][] parameters)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.Request.ExecuteStartRequest(String commandText, TeraTypeBase[][] parameters, ExecutionMode executionMode, Boolean asynchronous, Boolean isTrustedRequest)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand.ExecuteRequest(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, Boolean asynchronousCall, Boolean useStatementIndependence)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   в System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   в Teradata.SQLA.TdConnectInfo.Execute(DbCommand cmd, String keyword, DbDataReader& rdr, Int64& rowCnt, Int32& errPos) в v:\cm.client.ttu16.x\tdcli\qman\sqla\TdConnectInfo.vb:line 169
*******************************************************
07.11.2018 12:21:21
SQLA Version: 16.10.0.2
Driver Version: Teradata.Net 16.10.0.0
Teradata.Client.Provider.TdException (0x80004005): [.NET Data Provider for Teradata] [100038] Command did not complete within the time specified (timeout).
[Teradata Database] [3110] The transaction was aborted by the user.
[Socket Transport] [115003] The receive operation timed out. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005)
   в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpTcpTransport.ReadLanHeader(Buffer buffer, Int32 timeout, Int32 readBytes)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpTcpTransport.ReadLanHeader(Buffer buffer, Int32 timeout, Int32 readBytes)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpTcpTransport.Receive(Buffer buffer, Int32 timeout)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpSession.Receive(Buffer buffer, Int32 timeout)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpMessageManager.Receive(Int32 timeout)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpStartRequestManager.ReceiveStartMessage()
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpStartRequestManager.Action(ManagerActions step)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpStartRequestManager.RedriveAction(ManagerActions step)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.WpStartRequestManager.Action()
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.Request.ExecuteStartRequest(String commandText, TeraTypeBase[][] parameters, ExecutionMode executionMode, Boolean asynchronous, Boolean isTrustedRequest)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand.ExecuteRequest(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, Boolean asynchronousCall, Boolean useStatementIndependence)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.TdConnection.ChangeDatabase(String databaseName)
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.TdConnection.ExecuteInitializationStmts()
   в Teradata.Client.Provider.TdConnection.Open()
   в Teradata.SQLA.TdConnectInfo.GetSession() в v:\cm.client.ttu16.x\tdcli\qman\sqla\TdConnectInfo.vb:line 202
*******************************************************
```

Comment: That's strange. ANSI mode will still allow `sel,show`, etc., you probably still logon using Teradata mode, but it seems like SQLA doesn't load the syntax files for Teradata. When you look at the Database Explorer, does it show *myconnection(Teradata)*? Did you try to close & restart SQLA?

Comment: @dnoeth tried reloading even PC, problem persist for a long time. About myconnection(Teradata) - I provided pic, cant be sure

Comment: I've never seen that behaviour and there's indication of a bugfix up to 16.20.00.04. Is there any information in C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Teradata\SQL Assistant\SQLAError.Txt?

Comment: Doesn't seem there's any info in the error text. Try posting the question on Teradata's community forum, Steve Feinholz (SQLA developer) monitors it: https://community.teradata.com/t5/Tools-Utilities/bd-p/3 Or open an incident with TD Customer Service.

Comment: https://community.teradata.com/t5/Tools-Utilities/Teradata-SQL-assistant-bug-teradata-syntax-doesnt-work/m-p/83899#M11447 did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have accidentally toggled on View / ANSI SQL option, disabling solved the problem